# Why does this page scroll down to the bottom automatically?

Tags: safari, google-chrome

This happens only with Google Chrome and Safari. This is the page in question:
http://jqeedu.tuxfamily.org/pmr/

After opening the landing, click on `post your apartment`, a form is loaded via ajax, and the page automatically scrolls to the bottom and if you scroll up, it returns to the bottom again!

What is causing this?

Edit:
Sorry about this but I waited a few hours and then as it had to be fixed started experimenting with it and changed several things and ultimately fixed the issue. What I learned during the process is this:

1. I had an zero-width-and-height `iframe` on the page which served as the `target` for upload form, so that we could upload photos without page refresh. This `iframe` was the last element in the `body`. When I changed its place to top, the scrolling changed from insisting on the bottom position to insisting on page top position. Now the page wouldn't allow you to scroll down the page!
2. That was good news, because now I knew whatever it was, it was caused by the `iframe`. The `src` attribute of the `iframe` was set to `#`; I suspected this, and changed it to point to a real file (a blank html frame), made the file and the problem disappeared!

So, my analysis is this: The browser gets stuck on `loading` the file into the `iframe` and the process responsible for `loading` the content is left running. This process somehow does not let us scroll to an area where the `iframe` would go out of the `viewport`. This is a misbehavior of `webkit` engine and browsers built with `webkit` demonstrate this issue.

Finally, this is the snippet below shows the code of the `iframe` before and after the change, and the content of the new target file.

Buggy:

```
<iframe id="control_target" name="control_target" src="#"
 style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

Good:

```
<iframe id="control_target" name="control_target" src="blank.html" 
style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

blank.html:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body> </body>
</html>
```

Finally, I do not like to mark my own answer as accepted answer, so I put this in the body of the question, I wait for someone to explain a bit more about the nature of this issue or provide a better analysis. If such answer is provided, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I have just tried it and it works fine.  Using Chrome (Dev Channel)

Comment: Thanks Kinlan, you went to the page after the issue was fixed. Read my explanation above.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine in Safari 5, as well. Maybe an element at the bottom of your form is receiving focus, which would cause the page to scroll.

Comment: Tim, thank you for trying the page, and I'm sorry for the disappointment, please see my edit above, I found the answer and fixed before you see the page.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem I was having here. I had a generic function to focus on the first input of the page, and at a specific page the only input was a submit at the bottom of the page.